# Extension to control expenses

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions, magento-1.6

I was wondering if anyone know an extension for Magento that controls incomings and expenses related with processes. E.g.: I could add Office's supplies, cabs receipts, and so on. And by the end of every month for instance get Reports over all this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most advanced once comes from jTech. It calculates the profit per product (order) and allows for miscellaneous cost posts to be added as well as price of shipping or any other expenditure you might have per order or per month.

You can find the extension on [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/profit-and-loss-report-8375.html).

Another one I looked at but never used is from AS. The reason I choose jTech over AS is because I'm familiar with their code and it's relatively good in their extensions.

The AS extension can also be found on [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sales-profit-loss-report-1.html)

> On a side note: I would like to point out that Magento is not build
>   for accountancy and while you can do it by using various extensions I
>   would like to recommend however using software or an online platform
>   that is better suited for this.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the extension "MAGEpro Profit & Loss Report Extension" could be what you are looking for.
[Link to the Extension in Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magepro-profit-and-loss-report-extension.html)